# Enabling continuous deployment in Azure Web App for containers via ARM template

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template set up to deploy a Docker Image to an Azure App Service, but I'm having trouble finding out how to enable continuous deployment via any method other than the UI. There's instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ci-cd

But I want to use ARM templates so my setup is identical, repeatable and disposable - is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable continuous integration you can simply set the `DOCKER_ENABLE_CI` app setting:

```
resource site 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' = {
  properties: {
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'DOCKER_ENABLE_CI'
          value: 'true'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure devops as below demo to deploy docker container app

https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/docker/